# Sorting an array of "month numbers" from current month

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

We have an array of month numbers:

```
const months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
```

How would we sort this array from the current month back? e.g.

```
const currentMonth = 9; // September

months.sort((current, next) => { 
   // ... sorting algorithm here
});

console.log(months); // Prints Array [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,12,11,10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to sort since it's already sorted (just not the way you want):

```
const months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
const currentMonth = 9; 
months = months
             .slice(currentMonth)
             .concat(months.slice(0, currentMonth))
             .reverse();
```

Comment: Thats perfect, and yes you were right in eeded to think outside the box. There is an error in your code: `months` is a const so can't be modified.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(m => (12 + 9 - m) % 12 + 1)  + '' )
```